# How do I run the Vulkan API if I have no VK_KHR_swapchain extension?

Tags: c++, rendering, vulkan

I am on Windows 10, my GPU is GTX 880M.
When I use vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties to get supported extensions all I get is:

"VK_KHR_surface"
"VK_KHR_win32_surface"
"VK_EXT_debug_report"

However I have no "VK_KHR_swapchain" and if I try to enable "VK_KHR_swapchain" at instance creation, it just hangs.

Without "VK_KHR_swapchain" however, I can't create a swap chain, my debug callback from the validation layer gets called with this message:

> "Attemped to call vkCreateSwapchainKHR() but its required extension
>   VK_KHR_swapchain has not been enabled\n"

I can run games with Vulkan enabled just fine, as well as run the Cube demo from the Vulkan SDK, so there has to be some way I can create a Swapchain and render, right?

Or is there some kind of hack that has to be employed when a GPU doesn't have that extension?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`VK_KHR_swapchain` is a [device extension](https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?extension=VK_KHR_swapchain), not an instance extension. So you need to add it at device creation level instead.